# Allow minus sign nodeJS expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I'm passing URL params as such `h-3678/q-55/con-0.11` but since my latest developments I need to be able to pass a minus sign inside the **con** parameter like such: `h-3678/q-55/con--0.5/` but it's throwing errors using the expressions I've got right now?

```
let con_match = str.match(/(con-[^\\]+?)(?=\/)/);
let con = 0;
if (con_match && con_match.length) {
    con = con_match.shift().split('-').pop();
}
```

Comment: What's purpose of `[^\\]+?` ?

Comment: @anubhava I honestly have no idea, I'm not familiar with regex; it's a development program I'm learning

Comment: If it is a query param, it might be safer regex should probably be `.match(/[?&](con-[^\/]+)/)`, i.e. matching `?` or `&` and then `con-` with any 1+ chars other than `/` after.

Comment: and do you want to get 0.5 or -0.5 ?

Comment: Insead of splitting, extract the last number - `con = con_match[1].match(/-(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/)[1]`. Use a regex like `let con_match = str.match(/\b(con-[^\/]+)/);` also.

Comment: Your code is not throwing any error to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your number *always comes after `con-`*, you may use

```js
let strs = ["h-3678/q-55/con-0.11", "h-3678/q-55/con--0.5/"];
for (let i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  let str = strs[i];
  console.log(str);
  let con_match = str.match(/\bcon-(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/);
  let con = 0;
  if (con_match) {
    con = con_match[1]; 
  }
  console.log("Result:", con);
}
```

**Regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (the `\b` word boundary will only match `con` when it is not a part of another word, nor is preceded with a digit or `_`)
- `con-` - a literal substring
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 (`con_match[1]` value):

  - `-?` - an optional hyphen
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` and then 1+ digits

*Assuming there may be any text between `con` and the last number*, you may extract the `con` match with `/\b(con-[^\/]+)/` regex and then, after you obtain Group 1 value, extract the number from its end:

```js
let strs = ["h-3678/q-55/con-0.11", "h-3678/q-55/con--0.5/"];
for (let i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  let str = strs[i];
  console.log(str);
  let con_match = str.match(/\b(con-[^\/]+)/);
  let con = 0;
  if (con_match) {
    let m = con_match[1].match(/-(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/)
    if (m) { 
      con = m[1]; 
    }
  }
  console.log("Result:", con);
}
```

The second regex is `/-(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/`:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1:

  - `-?` - an optional hyphen
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` and then 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var str = 'h-3678/q-55/con-0.11';
var str = 'h-3678/q-55/con--0.5/';

let con_match = str.match(/(con\-([^\/]+)?)/);
let con = 0;
if (con_match && con_match.length) {
    console.log(con_match);
    con = con_match[2];
}

console.log(con);
```

The first one returns:
0.11

The second one returns:
-0.5